# Ci sono differenze tra "conto" e "conteggio" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-choice, difference

Non capisco bene se ci sono differenze tra i vocaboli "conto" e "conteggio" quando hanno il significato di "l'operazione di contare". Per esempio, quale parola, "conto" o "conteggio", dovrei usare per completare la frase seguente?

> Il problema consiste in fare il ________ di quanti cammini diversi ci sono per andare da casa a scuola percorrendo una distanza minima.

Comment: Secondo il Treccani, *conteggio* è l'operazione del contare.

Comment: Lo so, @egreg. Ma secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conto2/) anche "conto" può significare "l’operazione del contare". Quindi, posso usare tutti i due con lo stesso significato?

Comment: "conto" e "conteggio" sono sinonimi nella maggior parte dei casi, in altri no. "conto alla rovescia" o "conteggio alla rovescia", al ristorante dico "mi porti il conto per favore" e non "mi porti il conteggio per favore" (anche se non stona e si capisce) tuttavia posso dire "nel conto mi ha conteggiato la bevanda gratis", in certi contesti piú burocratici (tipo in bilanci o conguaglio anche se non sempre) si usa "conteggio" ad esempio "il conteggio dell´ufficio tributario ha stabilito la somma tot da pagare".

Comment: Si usa anche nel loro senso piú stretto e proprio "a conti fatti" o "a conteggi fatti" intercambiabilmente, e solo il primo come modo di dire. Penso che dovresti spulciare bene per capire la sottigliezza tra queste due parole i verbi "contare" e "conteggiare"

Comment: @mle "conteggio alla rovescia" praticamente non si usa mai, probabilmente mai sentito. Non ho mai sentito "mi porti il conteggio per favore". L'espressione più comune è definitivamente "mi porti il conto".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sono piccole sfumature di significato, ma "conto" mi sa più di appropriato a un problema con un calcolo non banale, mentre "conteggio" dà l'idea di fare qualcosa più meccanico, come contare i fagioli in un vaso.

Poi "fare il conto" è un'espressione fissa, quindi userei quella, ma dubito che ci sia una vera motivazione per cui "fare il conteggio" è sbagliato.

Per lo stesso motivo, direi "consiste *nel* fare", non "consiste *in* fare".

Comment: Non sono sicura di capire del tutto bene questa piccola sfumatura di cui stai parlando. Per esempio, se si usano tecniche di combinatoria per contare, questo rientra nella categoria di "calcolo non banale"? E, nel tuo esempio di "contare i fagioli in un vaso", se si usa il metodo statistico ["mark and recapture"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_and_recapture) (non so il nome in italiano) anche questo sarebbe "un calcolo non banale"?

Comment: Potresti fare un esempio di uso di "conteggio" in una frase? Non riesco a immaginarmene una in cui possa farlo senza usare il verbo "fare".

Comment: @Charo Sì, li considero "calcoli non banali". Con quel termine intendo qualunque cosa diversa dal contarli uno per uno: "uno, due, tre, ...".

Comment: @Charo C'è poi secondo me anche una differenza di registro: "fare" è più colloquiale, "conteggio" sa più di linguaggio tecnico/burocratese, quindi direi "effettuare il conteggio delle parole in Word" più spesso che "fare il conteggio delle parole" (che comunque non mi suona sbagliato).

Comment: Non sapevo dell'esistenza del verbo "conteggiare" menzionato da @mle (immagino che questo sia la causa del voto negativo). Tuttavia, secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conteggiare/), "conteggiare" significa "fare i conti" e questo sarebbe diverso dal contare uno per uno: "uno, due, tre, ...", no? Beh, il fatto è che ultimamente sto ricevendo molti voti negativi e di solito non riesco a capirne la ragione :(

Comment: @Charo, tieni presente che dalle mie parti (in Sicilia), si usa molto anche "cónta" (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conta/ -- http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/conta_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) (non é un termine siciliano peró, quindi puoi incontrarlo anche nel restante Italia)..  :)

Comment: Grazie, @mle: un altro vocabolo che non conoscevo!

Comment: @Charo, di nulla! Adesso spero hai tutto il quadro completo tra nomi e verbi e treccani per capire le sfumature di senso e significato. Ho una domanda sulla tua frase da completare, sarebbe "consiste in" o "consiste nel" ?